# How to hook SVN update with Subgit

Tags: git, subgit

I set up Subgit to sync between SVN and Git.
Subgit run a daemon process to listen SVN updating.

I want to run something after the daemon merge the SVN to Git repository,
What should I do?

Comment: Can you please describe what you're going to achieve by that? Do you host your Subversion and Git repositories on different machines?

Comment: @vadishev This is the story. I try to make Gerrit and Subgit works together. First I setup a git repository A with Subgit to sync a remote SVN repo. then I make a git mirror B from A for Gerrit use. So far, I use Gerrit replcation plugin to push mirror B to A, but manually update B from A to merge change from SVN by command `git remote update`. If Subgit updates from SVN and  call B to update automatically, that will be perfect.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

SubGit 2.0.x doesn't trigger any hooks when it fetches new revisions from Subversion repository. There is a feature request for that, feel free to upvote it: [SGT-360](http://issues.tmatesoft.com/issue/SGT-360).

As a workaround I'd suggest you to use a cron job that periodically runs the following command:

```
subgit fetch <GIT_REPO>
SubGit <version>
Translating SVN revisions to Git commits...
  rN => <hash>
Done.
```

You can also trigger Git-SVN sync remotely by running the following command:

```
$ cd <working_tree> && git push <remote> +:refs/subgit/command/fetch-sync
remote: Synchronizing SVN and Git...
remote:   translating SVN revisions to Git commits...
remote:     translated revision N to commit <hash>
remote: ... done.
```

It's possible to understand whether SubGit fetched new SVN revisions by parsing its output.

If you're going to use such periodical jobs, it makes sense to disable background translation process as it's not required anymore:

```
$ edit <GIT_REPO>/subgit/config
# [daemon]
#     idleTimeout = 0
$ subgit install <GIT_REPO>
```

Comment: I couldn't get figure out the proper GIT_REPO param from your example, but a simple `subgit fetch .` did the trick for me.